# Can theorems in coq (or in general) be proven without the use of previously proven lemmas?

Tags: logic, coq, proof

Given that proofs in coq are simply highly complex functions that can be built in any of a variety of ways, it seems to make sense that there would exist a coq proof of every theorem that involves neither previously proven theorems or `assert` statements.

For example, proving the commutativity of natural number addition is simple without any lemmas, even though it could be made simpler with lemmas:

```
Theorem plus_comm' :
  forall n m : nat, n + m = m + n.
Proof.
  induction n.
    intro m. simpl. induction m.
      reflexivity.
      simpl. rewrite <- IHm. reflexivity.
    intro m. simpl. rewrite -> IHn. induction m.
      reflexivity.
      simpl. rewrite <- IHm. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

But when I try to do the same thing for the commutativity of multiplication, I inevitably run into a situation where I require a fact about addition.

```
Theorem mult_comm' :
  forall n m : nat, n * m = m * n.
Proof.
  induction n.
    intro m. simpl. induction m.
      reflexivity.
      simpl. apply IHm.
    intro m. simpl. rewrite -> IHn. induction m.
      reflexivity.
      simpl. rewrite <- IHm. f_equal.
  (* left with goal:
      m + (n + m * n) = n + (m + m * n)
  *)
Abort.
```

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Coq's logic enjoys [cut-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem) which means that any proof involving intermediate lemmas (i.e. a lambda term with beta-redexes) can be, through a reduction algorithm, transformed into a direct proof (i.e. a term in normal form).

However this might come at the cost of an exponential blow-up: e.g. reducing `power 2 100` (as in the function `power` applied to `2` and `100` will produce a term of size `2 ^ 100` starting from a term of size `1 + 2 + 100`).

If you are trying to write proof-search algorithms, you may want to have a look at focusing. Given that you seem to want to focus on inductive proofs, you may want to look at Boyer & Moore's prover too.

Answer (score 1):

There is, of course, a proof without lemmas or asserts, as long as there is such a proof of the goal you are left with, `m + (n + m * n) = n + (m + m * n)`. Here is one, though it is not very elucidating:

```
remember (m*n) as o.
clear.
generalize dependent o.
generalize dependent m.
induction n; simpl; try reflexivity.
simpl.
intros m o.
rewrite <- (IHn m o).
remember (n+o) as p.
clear.
generalize dependent p.
induction m; simpl; try reflexivity.
intros p; rewrite (IHm p).
reflexivity.
```

The question of why you "need" a lemma can looked at from another angle:

Look at this proof of the commutativity of multiplication.Part of it is a proof of this funny fact about addition that you can shuffle the parenthesis around without changing the value. That seems to show up a bit in other proofs! Perhaps that fact would be a useful one to package up with a name. Then we can refer to it over and over again and the reader will understand what we are talking about, and it will not need a new proof every time.

Let's call a helper fact a "lemma". We'll call the process of moving it around and giving it a name "refactoring".

Comment: Thanks for providing the proof to the example, I wasn't able to come up with that. The reason I asked the question is because I'm researching automated theorem proving and trying to write tactics to automatize inductive proofs without using lemmas, so realizing that I just wasn't being creative enough is quite helpful to me. Thanks again.